# Tooltipster hover select and option not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, select, hover, tooltipster

Im not sure if this the right place to ask this but Im having a problem with tooltipster and IE. When I make an interactive tooltipster that shows on hover and add a form with an selectbox in it, it is impossible too select an option in IE because the tooltipster closes and your unable to make an selection.

I made an Plunker to quickly show the problem (open in IE): 
http://plnkr.co/lckgcT

```
<div id="corres_button" role="button">
  Hover me for the tooltipster!
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#corres_button').tooltipster({
    interactive: 'true',
    contentAsHTML:'true',
    trigger: 'hover',
    arrow: false,
    position: 'bottom',
    content: $('<div><span><strong>Try selecting an option in IE the tooltipster will close since it loses its hover</strong></span><form><label>Testing</label><select><option value="1">Test</option><option value="2">Test 2</option><option value="3">Test 3</option><option value="4">Test 4</option></select></form></div>')
  });
});
```

I tried adding all kinds of css options too the form select options (display: block/inline-block etc) and playing with the Z-index. But nothing works and the tooltipster keeps closing when I 'open' the select options.

Im sorry for the bad english and I hope the problem is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it and updated the Plunker with the fix.

The problem wasnt just with tooltipster its with how IE implements the selectbox. 
You can fix it by adding the `event.stopPropagation` too the select.

### Default fix:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").mouseleave(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

By fixing this in your tooltipster you need too add the following too the the functionReady of the tooltipster

### Tooltipster fix:

```
functionReady: function(origin) {
    origin.tooltipster('content').find('select').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).mouseleave(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
}
```